# Client server app difference in byte sizes from both perspectives

Tags: .net, sockets, arrays

Recently i've been learning networking and sockets and [found a really cool article about a client and server](http://csharp.net-informations.com/communications/csharp-client-socket.htm). i made a console app in c# as the server(exactly like the tutorial) and then i made a forms app(Also in the tutorial) with a few differences.

Both the server and the app work fine. Whats worrying me though is that (for now im only testing with strings) my input into the stream seems really small. .[image: See the image here..]. You'll see that my outstream array has 43 items in it. and the text is only "this is a really short piece of text".

However the server perceives the outstream as 8219 items of length. Also, after debugging, the server app also alter the string a little.

[image: Server app]

As you can see from the image that the server app sees the input stream as 8219 items.
Is there some sort of mistake that im making. Also, before sending back the stream i write it to the console. the \0 's seem to be invisible(as well as inspecting in debuggers text visualizer-however in the console they do take up space but not in the text visualizer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The buffers you are allocating for reading are of the size of the underlying read buffer, which is exactly 8192 bytes here. When you read from your stream, you specify 8192 (buffer size) as the read size, but if you take a look at the MSDN documentation, the `Read` method can return whenever it wants, if there was data to read :

> The Read operation reads as much data as is available, up to the number of bytes specified by the size parameter.

What happens is that the `Read` method reads all the available data (your string), then return and leaves the rest untouched (zeroed). The 8219 bytes is the 8192 buffer with your additional string concatenated (27 chars).

You should note that when you work with a stream, you should either know exactly the size of what you are going to receive, or send this size before the actual data. This is because there is no guarantee that one `Write` call will be exactly one `Read` call on the receiving end. Two write can be received in one read, or one write can be received in two read, you can't know. What is guaranteed is that the data will be received and not corrupted (unless there is a big problem, like a crash).

Using `NetworkStream` directly is probably not the best option here for you. You can wrap it in a `BinaryWriter` and `BinaryReader`, and use the `Write(String)` and `ReadString()` method. This way you won't even need to allocate buffers.